# API request doesnt work on heroku properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, heroku

I am programming a node.js app and i need to deploy it on heroku.
In it, i am getting 3 APIs, one of them requires an API key from Rapidapi.
In my local directory everything works fine. But as soon as I upload my app to heroku the one that requires the API key doesn't work anymore.

Here is my code:

```js
//where i am accessing my api 
fetch(`/geodb?namePrefix=${city}`).then(response => { //fetching country data to city name

        response.json().then(response => {
        response.json = response;
        var citylenght = Object.keys(response.data).length;
        } 
        
        
//and here is the actual fetch request:
 app.get('/geodb', async (request, response) => {

  let cityname = request.query.namePrefix; //getting parameter for the url

  let api_response = await fetch(`https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities?namePrefix=${cityname}`, {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.API_KEY //loading api key from .env file
    }
    
  });
  let json = await api_response.json();
  response.json(json);
  });
```

On my localhost everything is working fine, but when I am accessing my app on heroku the browser console says the following:

```
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to
> object
>     at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
>     at api.js:13 (anonymous) @ api.js:13 Promise.then (async) (anonymous) @ api.js:11 Promise.then (async) lookup @ api.js:9
> receiveData @ listeners.js:7 onclick @ (index):43 (anonymous) @
> (index):187
```

That tells me that the app is unable to access the api data and thats why the answer is undefined. The heroku log doesn't show any error either.

By the way: When I am just using the 2 other apis that don't need any api key, and where i didnt define any headers, then everything works fine.

I would be very happy if you could help me because I need to get it done very soon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Heroku, you set your Environment Variables in the application config, not by uploading `.env`. You can either use the web interface or the `heroku config` command if you use the CLI tool.

Make the key "API_KEY" and the value whatever it should be from your `.env` file (and probably don't deploy that file, they are usually kept local and not included in source control or deployed to the hosting platform. This part is just advice though!)

Comment: I added the api key now with `heroku config:set API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE` and it works!! thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear it :) If you mark with as the accepted answer, people will know the question is no longer outstanding.